# How to setup a docker for ROS kinetic?

Tags: docker, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to setup a docker for ROS kinetic ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302721/how-to-setup-a-docker-for-ros-kinetic-?/) by [emmanuelovalle](https://answers.ros.org/users/37378/emmanuelovalle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OSRF actually has pre-made docker files with ROS installs for you to start with (https://hub.docker.com/r/osrf/ros/). After that, you just need to add your own use case specific files / configs / needs on top of a base ubuntu + ROS install.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emmanuelovalle](https://answers.ros.org/users/37378/emmanuelovalle/) on 2018-09-12**:
I already pulled the container. Do you have a step by step that I can follow? I am a beginner in docker.